# Why can't < 250 rep. people close their questions as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions, privileges

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380780). Later, I found an answer to another question that answered my question. I was about to close the question as duplicate, but I realized that I didn't have the 250-rep privilege to close my question (I was used to my SO account with 300 rep). The question was eventually closed as a duplicate, but it leaves me with two questions:

1. Why is the close privilege at 250 rep?
2. Should we lower the close privilege, or allow any user to close their question as duplicate? Why or why not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even without 250 reputation, you can still *flag* your own question as a duplicate, and submit "Yes" in the form in the "Does this answer your question" post notice. You can also flag to close it for other reasons and let the Close Votes review queue take care of it. You'll gain a helpful flag in the process.

Why is voting to close your own question a privilege? Well, because it's **symmetric**; if you're able to vote to close something, you're able to vote to reopen it too. It makes sense *not* to allow everybody to vote to reopen their own question; otherwise almost everybody would be inclined to do that.